# Google App Engine for e-commerce web site?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just learned about Google App Engine, and I must say it is fantastic.
But, based on the nature of Google app engine, is it possible to design an e-commerce website using Google App Engine? I mean, based on the huge cloud server platform provided by Google App Engine, we have a built-in *content delivery network*. But, should it be that way?

Comment: What do the last two sentences of your question have to do with the first two?

Comment: Try asking in the new [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions) site.  I hope the StackOverflow designers create a flag to conveniently cross-post a question there because that site is very suitable for general advice.  It would also reduce the "too broad" objections that some people raise here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is it possible to design an e-commerce website using Google App Engine?`

If you want to develop such a website then why not go for more portable alternative? For example, develop your e-commerce website on `web2py` or `django`. Both can be hosted on GAE (in case of web2py it just needs minor modifications). GAE imposes a lot of restrictions, but you can stop worrying about system administration and scaling as GAE takes care of it.

If you want to focus on developing an e-commerce website rather than on learning development specifically for GAE then I suggest you use web2py, because porting is very easy.

http://wiki.web2py.com/Deploying_web2py_on_Google_App_Engine_GAE_

I have tested it myself, you can check it if you like: http://memstats-w2py.appspot.com/

Comment: I also disagree with the "not that mature" assertion, there are several arguments against GAE but not being mature hasn't been one for several years.

Comment: @DanielChatfield when I was working on GAE, there was no support for SSL on custom domain names.

Comment: @DanielChatfield "not that mature", I admit using a wrong term for this. I should have rather said it imposes a lot of restrictions. I have modified my answers. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google App Engine supports SSL over custom domain names.
 https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl